# ClasscastException in servlet

Tags: java, servlets, classcastexception

I try to implement a plugin system in a servlet. I've written a class to load plugin that use URLClassLoader to load the jar files and Class.forname to load the class.
Here is my code:
This part create the url class Loader:

```java
    public PluginLoader(ServletContext context, String[] pluginName, String[] classToLoad) throws PluginLoaderException{
            this.context = context;
            urls= new URL[pluginName.length];
            nameToURL(pluginName);
            //create class loader
            loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
            //loading the plug-in
            loadPlugin(classToLoad);
        }
```

This one initialize the url:

```java
    private void nameToURL(String[] pluginName) throws PluginLoaderException{
            try{
                for(int i=0;i<pluginName.length;i++){
                    urls[i] = context.getResource(pluginName[i]);
                }
            }
```

Finally this one create the object:

```java
    private void loadPlugin(String[] classToLoad) throws PluginLoaderException{
            try{
                iTest = (ITest) Class.forName(classToLoad[0],true,loader).newInstance();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                throw new PluginLoaderException(e.toString());
            }
        }
```

I have managed to create the object because I can manipulate it and retrieve the interface it implements but I can't cast it in ITest to manipulate it in the application. I have a ClassCastException tplugin.toto.Toto cannot be cast to fr.test.inter.ITest .
It's strange because Toto implements ITest.

Does anyone has an idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've created a classoader issue -- when you test with `instanceof ITest`, you are using the copy of `ITest` loaded by the default classloader, but you are testing an instance loaded by the `URLClassloader`. That classloader has loaded its own copy of `ITest`, which, as far as the JVM is concerned, is a completely different type.

Comment: I understand your explanation but why when I try this code in a java standard application it's working ?

Comment: In a standard Java app the default classloader is completely different, so I would suppose it's working due to a lucky interraction between those two cls -- or that it's not working due to an unlucky fit in the servlet container case :) You are not passing an explicit parent classloader to `URLClassloader`. What will be the parent in that case?

Comment: Thanks  your explanation are very helpful, like you said passing the default classloader at the URLClassloader solve the problem. Have a nice day

Comment: It's nice to accept the answer, scarankle, if you conclude it was helpful. Just StackOverlow etiquette.